# Command not working with subprocess.run but does work with subprocess.call

Tags: python, windows, cmd, msbuild, subprocess

I am trying to use `subprocess.run` with a custom argument, that works both directly from windows cmd, and from `subprocess.call`, but not with `subprocess.run`, as suggested by [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output).

This works:

```
    retcode = subprocess.call(build_command_line, shell=True)
```

This fails:

```
    result = subprocess.run([build_command_line], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and outputs

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 551, in new_CreateProcess
    return getattr(_subprocess, original_name)(app_name, patch_arg_str_win(cmd_line), *args)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

even though I run with administrator.

Not that it should matter, but for completeness:

`build_command_line` is:

```
'"C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\MSBuild.exe" "C:\\code\\EPMD\\Kodex\\Solutions\\Kodex.All.sln" /t:REBUILD /p:Configuration=RELEASE'
```

How do I get it to work with `subprocess.run`?

Comment: either build_command line is a string (and then you are passing a list with a single string) or it is a list (and then you are passing a list with a single element which is a list), please clarify the contents of build_ccommand line, can't get what it is from what you wrote

Comment: @E.Serra Edited. It is a string. So i should call with no `[]`?

Comment: `[build_command_line]` is wrong. Just use `build_command_line`. In Windows you can always use a command-line string. If you pass an `args` list instead of a command line, `subprocess.Popen` uses `subprocess.list2cmdline` to build the command line according to the rules used by MSVC and WinAPI `CommandLineToArgvW`. With `[build_command_line]`, the whole command line is one item in the list, so all of the quotes get escaped as literal characters.

Comment: shell=True allows you to write whatever command as a string, the usual way of ccalling it is to pass it a list with the arguments and values as elements, e.g. ['ls', '-a', '-l'],  break your command into a true list and give it a go

Comment: @E.Serra, it's Windows, so passing a command-line string does not require `shell=True`. If the script needs to support Unix, then in that case it should use an args list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was my understanding of `subprocess.run`

correct call:

```
result = subprocess.run(build_command_line, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```